# How to select last_insert_id?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, last-insert-id

I have an SQL statement that returns more than one value:
[image]

In my code I then need to call the last ID that was inserted. I have seen some examples about `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` but they all seems to be for insert statements. I just want to show the last inserted id.

So from the image below I would only need to select ID 13.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` .

**Query**

```
SELECT dl.* FROM driver_log dl
WHERE dl.Company_ID = 76 AND dl.Manifesr=tNo = 8199
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you want to select only the ID, then use `MAX` function.

```
SELECT MAX(dl.ID) as ID 
FROM driver_log dl
WHERE dl.Company_ID = 76 AND dl.Manifesr=tNo = 8199;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the MAX function like

```
SELECT max(id) FROM driver_log dl
WHERE dl.Company_ID = 76 AND dl.Manifesr=tNo = 8199
```

Answer (score 1):

simple way is that Select last row data by query.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName order by ID desc limit 1
```